# Calling a function on each member of an object in c#

Tags: c#, .net

### **I want to call a function on each member of an object in C#. What is the best way to do this?**

Below are some details of my exact situation, I do not believe this is necessary to answer the question but some people have asked for more info:

> I have a class with a lot of members, over 100. Unfortunately, this is
> unavoidable as this is a simulation software package. These variables
> are all captured in State objects and timestamped.
>
> A second class called a Delta represents the differences between one
> State and another. For example, if State1 has x, y,  z = 0, 0, 0 and
> State2 has x, y, z = 1, 0, 0: then the Delta from State1 to State2 has
> x, y, z = 1, null, null.
>
> Deltas are then serialized into protocol buffers and sent across the
> network, to reconstruct the current state at the other end.
>
> States have the following methods: GetDelta(State reference) which
> returns the Delta between the reference State (the older state) and
> the State object, ApplyDelta(Delta delta) which updates the state with
> the information from the delta (in the example above if you called
> State1.ApplyDelta(delta) you would receive State2), and
> Interpolate(State reference, double factor) which interpolates between
> the reference state and the state according to the factor (a number
> between 0 and 1).
>
> States are actually an abstract idea. In the code, there are many
> different kinds of states - for the weather, the world, various
> simulation objects - but they all implement an interface that requires
> them to implement those 3 methods.
>
> In a trivial case implementing all of these functions is simple. Even
> if it's a complex case, it's simple - but it is a lot of lines of
> code. 100 members require 100 lines to declare the members in the
> state, 100 lines to declare the members in the delta, 100 lines for
> each of the 3 methods above - that's 500 lines of code that are
> potentially error-prone.
>
> **How can I call the same function on every member of an object?**
> -
>
> I have considered putting all the members into a dictionary, list, or
> array, but I don't think it would be very clean since the data is
> heterogeneous. I could have one collection per type, which would be a
> lot cleaner but would tightly couple the data type to the way it's
> handled.
>
> I know this is a long post for a simple question, but obviously a lot
> of architectural decisions have been made already and I didn't want to
> present an XY problem. Nothing is set in stone, if there's a better
> architecture then I will consider it.
>
> Here is some example code of how states function: ```C# interface
> IInterpolatable<S, D> {
> D GetDelta(S reference);
> S ApplyDelta(D delta);
> S Interpolate(S reference, double factor); }
>
> class State : IInterpolatable<State, State.Delta> {
> public int a;
> public decimal b;
> public boolean c;
>
> ````
> class Delta
> {
>     public int? a;
>     public decimal? b;
>     public boolean? c;
> }
>
> public Delta GetDelta(State reference)
> {
>     if (reference == null)
>     {
>         return GetDelta(new State());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return new Delta
>         {
>             a = reference.a != a ? a : null,
>             b = reference.b != b ? b : null,
>             c = reference.c != c ? c : null,
>         };
>     }
> }
>
> public State ApplyDelta(Delta delta)
> {
>     if (delta == null)
>     {
>         return ApplyDelta(new Delta());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return new State
>         {
>             a = delta.a ?? a,
>             b = delta.b ?? b,
>             c = delta.c ?? c,
>         };
>     }
> }
>
> public State Interpolate(State reference, double factor)
> {
>     if (reference == null)
>     {
>         return Interpolate(new Ship(), factor);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // Note: There are linear interpolation functions for the used types
>         return new Ship
>         {
>             a = lerp(reference.a, a, factor),
>             b = lerp(reference.b, b, factor),
>             c = lerp(reference.c, c, factor),
>         };
>     }
> } } ```
> ````
>
> You can imagine the data flow as something like:
>
> 1. The simulation generates a new state
> 2. A delta between that state and the previous is generated using GetDelta
> 3. The delta is sent across the network to the client
> 4. The client regenerates the new state by using ApplyDelta on the previous state
> 5. The client then interpolates between the previous to the new state using Interpolate
>
> Of course it's more complex than that, but that's the gist of it.
>
> EDIT: Some people were interested to know how syncing between client
> and server works in this model.
>
> Deltas are wrapped in a packet that contains a timestamp, and the
> timestamp of the reference state. Then they are sent to the client.
> When the client receives the packet they send back an acknowledgment
> with the timestamp. The server tracks the newest timestamp
> acknowledged by the client and generates the delta between that
> acknowledged state and the state it wants to send to the client.
>
> Example (each number is 1 timestep, network latency is 1 step):
>
> 1. The server grabs new state S1, since it has not received any acks from the client it generates a delta D1 between an empty state and S1.
>    This state is sent across the network to the client. The client is
>    waiting.
> 2. The server grabs S2, still no acks so D2 is generated between an empty state and S2. The client receives D1, and uses it to generate
>    the state S1. The client sends an ack back to the server.
> 3. The server receives the ack from the client for S1. The server grabs S3, and generates D3. Since S1 was acked D3 is the delta between
>    S3 and S1. The client is waiting - looks like D2 never showed up!
> 4. The server grabs S4, and again since S1 was the latest state acked, D4 is the delta between S4 and S1. The client receives D3, generates
>    S3, and sends back an ack.
> 5. etc
>
> Someone gave an example: "what would the server do if x increments
> every state, but 5 packets fail to be sent to the client?" The answer
> is that since deltas are relative to something, it will first send
> x+1, then x+2, then x+3, then x+4, then x+5, then finally it receives
> an ack so it can send x+1 next.
>
> Sorry if that isn't clear, I can provide more information to clear it
> up if there's a problem.

Comment: I think it would be better to show the code example of declaring these states. likely you could just write a helper method, but its hard to tell from the abstract wording of the question, where as it would be easier to just digest the code

Comment: @MichaelRandall Hi, thanks for your comment. I have added some example code showing how the described mechanisms work!

Comment: *500 lines of code that are potentially error-prone* Even if you could loop through the members, you can't escape the need to declare them. Have you considered code generation, i.e. writing a program to write the code? .

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if some delta packets get lost on the network? Imagining a simulation of filling a bath tub, where our only property is "Level" to show the % of how full the tub is:
The "host" creates a new Tub object, set's Level to 0. The "client" gets that full state on startup. Now the "host" generates a new Delta (+1) every 1 second. After 100 seconds the "host" stops

A network outage lasts 5 seconds. The "client" received "Level += 1" 95 times but missed those 5 in the middle. Is our end state that the "host" says 100% but the "client" says 95%? How do they sync up?

Comment: @JeffWhitty Like I said, it's more complex than I posted :P There are fairly standard solutions to this problem. I will try and answer simply. Before being transmitted deltas are wrapped in a packet that has a timestamp and the timestamp of the referenced state (eg T = 100, R = 95). The client sends an ACK back to the server when they receive a delta, this ACK contains the timestamp of the packet that was received. Next time the server wants to generate a packet, it knows what the last ACK'ed timestamp was, and generates the delta between the newest state and that reference state. more in post

Comment: @JohnWu Yep, code generation is an option too. I'm not sure the best way to go about it in c#.net but would be interested in an answer!

Comment: I'm writing my own code generation in python, that might be the solution here, but I'm sure someone with C# code generation experience might be able to demonstrate something nicer!

Comment: Not entirely sure why this question was closed, if someone could suggest a more focused question that "calling a function on every member of an object" then I would be thankful. I can't really think of a way to focus it more.

Comment: If anyone has read this post and thought they can see a second question in there, please let me know so I can remove it!!!

Comment: @user-024673 - Fair enough, just wanted to see you'd considered it really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using python for code generation.

```py
class DataTypes:
  INT = 'int'
  DOUBLE = 'double'
  ...

class Field:
  def __init__(self, name, data_type):
    self.name = name
    self.data_type = data_type

  @property
  def definition(self):
    return f'public {self.type} {self.name};'

  ...

class State:
  def __init__(self, name, fields):
    self.name = name
    self.fields = fields

  @property
  def definition(self):
    lines = []

    lines.append(f'public class {self.name}')
    lines.append('{')

    for field in self.fields:
      lines.append(field.definition)

    ...

    lines.append('}')

    return '\n'.join(lines)

  ...

foo = State('Foo', [
  Field('a', DataTypes.INT),
  Field('b', DataTypes.DOUBLE),
]
```

Works great, maintainable, fast, simple.